# Type checking in Python

Tags: python, types

How can I check the type of function's parameters? For example,

```
def hello(x):
   # check if x is tuple
   # check if x is dictionary.
   ...
```

### EDIT

```
isinstance(x, type(()))
isinstance(x, type({}))
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't.

You should never be unsure of the type of a thing in python; it's basically impossible to check accurately. While it is possible to do some naïve surface-level checking, the problem is that python is very flexible. Your function shouldn't care if it's passed a dict or something that behaves exactly like a dict, and the best way to deal with this is to not check at all.

The real question is "why don't I know what the type of something is?"

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to check that, you can use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance)

See also this [comparison of type checking methods](http://www.siafoo.net/article/56) and why you should not check!

Comment: Why the downvote? I clearly stated "if you **really** want to check that..." and "you should **not** check".

Answer (score 2):

Python's best practice is to use duck typing: if it walks like duck and quacks like a duck, treat it like a duck. So, what you care is not whether something is a dict or a list: you care whether or not you can *treat is* as such (in the duck analogy, you don't care if it's a human, as long as it can walk like a duck and quack like a duck).

For instance, if you want to extract an element:

```
def get_element(obj, index):
 return obj[index]
```

works as long as the object you passed to it understands what does `[index]` means.

Now, you can actually use `isinstance` to check if an object is an instance of a class, but this is normally used for introspection purposes. I have used it, on occasion, instead of duck typing, only to regret later and go back to Python's best practice.

So, I recommend that you look at what you are trying to achieve and see if you could use duck typing instead.

Cheers.